# kafka broker 2.1.x and clients versions compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka

We are planning to upgrade our Kafka client from 2.0.0 to a later version that is be compatible with Kafka broker 2.1.x .

What is the latest Kafka client version that is compatible with Kafka broker 2.1.x?

Is it possible to upgrade from 2.0.0 to 2.3.x?

Is there a compatibility matrix for latest Kafka broker and client versions? Did anyone face any issues with such upgrades?

Comment: Clients above 1.x work for all broker versions down to 0.10.1 for all basic produce and consume interaction

Comment: You can check this: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#protocol_compatibility